# Loop through a class which contains variables

Tags: c#, class

I would like to compare two classes that look like this

```
public class Order
{
        public string KundNummer, KundNamn, ErReferens, VarReferens, KontraktsNummer, Betvillk, Levvillk, Levsatt, Speditor,
            Resenh, Projekt, OrderDatum, LeveransDatum, ErtOrdernr, LagerbokfDatum, KundPostAdr, KundPostAdr2, KundGLN, KundPostnr, 
            KundOrt, KundLandKod, KundLand, KundVATnr, KundDistrikt, KundSaljare, KundText1, KundText2, KundText3, KundSprak,
            KundValuta, KundRabattAvtal, KundRabattAvtalBenamning, KundPrislista, KundPrislistaBenamning, KundALnamn, KundALpostAdr, KundALpostAdr2, KundALGLN, KundALpostnr, KundALort,
            KundALlandKod, KundALland;
        public double OrderNummer, Fakturarabatt, Frakt, Expavg, Brutto, Netto, ExklMoms, Totalt, Moms, Avrundn, KundValutaKurs, KundValutaEnhet;
        public int EUPeriodSamman, InklMoms, EjKlar, Levererad, Malukerad, BestallningSkapad, Ordererk,
            Plocklista, Foljesedel, ExtraOrderdokument, Restorder, Faktura, KundSparaText, KundExport, KundRantefakturering, KundKravbrev,
            KundKravavgift, KundRestnoteraEj, KundSamlingsfakturera;
    }
```

i want to compare two objects of this class for logging which fields in my database that changed.

```
public string OrderUppdateraOrder(Order order)
    {
        Order OrderToCompare = new Order();
        OrderToCompare = OrderVisaOrderInformation(order.OrderNummer);

        //then the code goes on to make the changes to the database from the class order
        //while OrdertoComapre still have the values from before this function was called
    }
```

So is it possible to loop through these classes and compare them or do I have to write an **if** for every variable in my class? :)

Or maybe convert it to a List? I don't know? :P

Thank you for answers

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240385/can-i-use-reflection-to-get-an-existing-variable-by-providing-its-name

However, that's bad practice.

Comment: You can always use reflection and compare each property on the instances to the others. But depending on what ORM you are using, you might have built in support for finding everything that has changed. To use refleciton check my blog post: http://blog.filipekberg.se/2011/10/08/exploring-reflection-finding-a-value-in-any-of-the-objects-properties/ *Remember though that using Reflection can cause performance penelties!*

Comment: my God... is there any possibility of your this class to get into smaller component classes... rather a normalized form... :)

Comment: perhaps like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986572/hows-to-quick-check-if-data-transfer-two-objects-have-equal-properties-in-c/986617#986617 ? (noting that that is property-based - would need minor tweaks to work with fields)

Comment: thank you i will check the sites :)

Comment: You want to check that every field in one instance of an `order` class is equal to another instance of another instance of an `order`?

Comment: So if I understand this you have an instance of the order object and want to compare the information in your instance with the information in your database? How do you communicate with your db, linq, entity, sql?

Comment: It's entirely clear exactly what you want to do here. Do you want to see if *any* field is different and in that case get an indication that "something has changed", or do you want to compare every single field and log all differences in some way? The most straight-forward way to do it is indeed with reflection, but the exact implementation differens depending on what results you want to achieve.

Comment: bonCodigo: I dont know :) its for visma api program and i need one variable for each field the user inputs

Comment: Anders Holmström: i want to log if there is a difference and log the difference something like this    CustomerNumber: changed from 456 to 345

Comment: I HAVE to mention this: Please use better variable names, for your own sake and the sake of your colleagues. Using abbreviations in variable names is most of the time a really bad habit. When you look at your code in months again, can you remember what all your abbreviations mean? Just use better variable names, it comes with no penalty except of having to write a bit more (which is hardly an argument with a good editor).

Comment: user1793714: i named them like the fields are named in the swedish version of: visma administration 2000.

Comment: Perhaps in his language or client's, these variables make sense. However it's important for readability and managing your code later - even it's your or by someone else.

Comment: but you might be right but i have documented everything in an word file   :)

Comment: Now that you've clarified the purpose, perhaps you could adapt [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060382/comparing-2-objects-and-retrieve-a-list-of-fields-with-different-values) to allow for fields

Comment: @Dendei, Just a side-note: Not that it matters but is this homework? If not, you might want to store "Kund" (Customer in Swedish) as a reference on the Order instead of storing all the fields on it.

Comment: @Filip Ekberg im a intern :) but yes my customer class is just as big with only customer fields, i have some in order to because in visma the  ordercustomer fields are not the same as the customer fields. i prob could split both up and make one new class containing the ones they have in common. And split my functions dealing with them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i want to log if there is a difference and log the difference something like this CustomerNumber: changed from 456 to 345

The best option is probably just to use reflection to crawl over the public properties and fields, comparing them. This will have less code to compare, but will have a performance overhead. You can greatly reduce that overhead using tools like FastMember:

```
static class Program {
    static void Main()
    {
        Order o1 = new Order { Resenh = "abc" },
              o2 = new Order { Resenh = "abc" };
        ShowDiffs(o1, o2); // {nothing}
        o2.Resenh = "def";
        ShowDiffs(o1, o2); // Resenh changed from abc to def
    }
    static void ShowDiffs<T>(T x, T y)
    {
        var accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(typeof(T));
        if (!accessor.GetMembersSupported) throw new NotSupportedException();
        var members = accessor.GetMembers();

        foreach (var member in members)
        {
            object xVal = accessor[x, member.Name],
                   yVal = accessor[y, member.Name];
            if (!Equals(xVal, yVal))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} changed from {1} to {2}",
                    member.Name, xVal, yVal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @LukeHennerley Yes... it would. The generic type can be inferred from the arguments supplied to the method call.

Comment: this looks like exactly what i want but im just checking up on things i dont understand so well. so bear with me i you are waiting for solved mark ^^

Comment: is TypeAccessor from FastMember? cant find much on it? i'll test it :)

Comment: @Dendei yes, that is from FastMember - basically, it is a small utility library I wrote that wraps up the most common reflection operations, and bundles in some meta-programming for performance

Comment: @Dendei you could do exactly the same thing with `typeof(T).GetFields(...)`, and `someField.GetValue(obj)` - it would just be much slower

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this approach can help you

```
public class Order
{
    public string KundNummer, KundNamn, ErReferens, VarReferens, KontraktsNummer, Betvillk, Levvillk, Levsatt, Speditor,
        Resenh, Projekt, OrderDatum, LeveransDatum, ErtOrdernr, LagerbokfDatum, KundPostAdr, KundPostAdr2, KundGLN, KundPostnr,
        KundOrt, KundLandKod, KundLand, KundVATnr, KundDistrikt, KundSaljare, KundText1, KundText2, KundText3, KundSprak,
        KundValuta, KundRabattAvtal, KundRabattAvtalBenamning, KundPrislista, KundPrislistaBenamning, KundALnamn, KundALpostAdr, KundALpostAdr2, KundALGLN, KundALpostnr, KundALort,
        KundALlandKod, KundALland;
    public double OrderNummer, Fakturarabatt, Frakt, Expavg, Brutto, Netto, ExklMoms, Totalt, Moms, Avrundn, KundValutaKurs, KundValutaEnhet;
    public int EUPeriodSamman, InklMoms, EjKlar, Levererad, Malukerad, BestallningSkapad, Ordererk,
        Plocklista, Foljesedel, ExtraOrderdokument, Restorder, Faktura, KundSparaText, KundExport, KundRantefakturering, KundKravbrev,
        KundKravavgift, KundRestnoteraEj, KundSamlingsfakturera;

    public static bool operator ==(Order left, Order right)
    {
        foreach (var field in left.GetType().GetFields())
        {
            object valueLeft = field.GetValue(left);
            object valueRight = field.GetValue(right);

            if (!object.Equals(valueLeft, valueRight))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Order left, Order right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }

}
```

Comment: `object.Equals(valueLeft,valueRight)` would be more appropriate than using a comparer and checking for 0; also, if you see the comments, the intent is a memberwise breakdown of changes

Answer (score 1):

Ok from how I understand you - you have a method which will retreive an `Order` object from the database and an `Order` object which you may have intially got from a database, but modified. You want to check if one, or many orders have change without saying:

> For each order if Database.A equals Your.A etc.

I would put your check into one place and override the `Equals` method.

```
  public class Order
  {
    public int Id;
    public string SomeProp;
    public string AnotherProp;
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
      Order orderToCompare = (Order)obj;
      return (SomeProp == orderToCompare.SomeProp && AnotherProp == orderToCompare.AnotherProp);
    }
  }
```

Then have two methods, one for updating a single order and one for updating many orders.

```
private void UpdateOrder(Order o)
{
  //Get the corresponding order from the database (I suspect Entity Framework here in order to get an object?)
  Order dbOrder = OrderVisaOrderInformation(o.Id);
  if (dbOrder.Equals(o))
  {
    //Do some update
  }
}
private void UpdateManyOrders(List<Order> orders)
{
  var dbOrders = (from order in orders
                  select OrderVisaOrderInformation(order.Id));
  List<Order> ordersToUpdate = dbOrders.Where(x => !x.Equals(orders.First(y => y.Id == x.Id))).ToList();
  foreach (Order orderToUpdate in ordersToUpdate)
  {
    //Update the order
  }
}
```

This may be wrong but from how I understand your question, this is what you want to do.

Comment: If you see the comments, the requirement is a memberwise breakdown of changes. Also: if you override `Equals` you should also override `GetHashCode` - and for this many members that is high-maintenance

Comment: @MarcGravell I see... I started doing this answer whilst the many comments were happening. Thanks.

Comment: I can relate... I have a deleted answer doing an optimized `Expression` comparison ;p

Comment: sorry for if im slow at answering im just checking through all the posts :) but im not sure, the order object in public string OrderUppdateraOrder(Order order) function is what the user writes in to change in the database. And before the changes take place i make an same object with the values before the changes take place so i can compare and log the differences. so one object has the values the database have right now and one have the values that will overwrite the current ones in the database. hope this makes sense